# Regularity of elliptic partial differential equation with mixed Dirichlet-Robin boundary condition, to prove $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

I have [posted this problem on Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670698/regularity-of-elliptic-partial-differential-equation-with-mixed-dirichlet-robin) but got no reply.

When I deal with the wave equation with dynamical boundary condition, I am confused by the regularity of the following elliptic partial differential equation with mixed Dirichlet-Robin boundary condition:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u+u=f, &x\in\Omega,\\
 u+\partial_{\nu}u=g, &x\in\Gamma_{1}, 
\\u=0,&x\in\Gamma_{0}.
\end{cases}
$$
where

- $f\in L^{2}(\Omega),g\in L^{2}(\Gamma_{1})$
- $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded annular domain with smooth boundary $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$,
- $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ are disjoint relatively open respectively.

We can prove that there exists a weak solution $u\in H^{1}_{\Gamma_{0}}(\Omega)$ by Lax-Milgram theorem and $\Delta u\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ according to the equation. But can we prove that $u$ also belongs to $H^{2}(\Omega)$?

Moreover, if $K(x)$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and satisfy

- $K=K^{Tr}$
- $\lambda|\xi|^{2}\leq K_{ij}\xi_{i}\xi_{j}\leq \Lambda|\xi|^{2},0<\lambda\leq\Lambda$
- every $k_{ij}\in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$

for the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
-{\rm div}(K(x)\nabla u)+u=f, &x\in\Omega,\\
 u+\partial^{K}_{\nu}u=g, &x\in\Gamma_{1}, 
\\u=0,&x\in\Gamma_{0}.
\end{cases}
$$
where $\partial_{\nu}^{K}u=k_{ij}u_{i}\nu_{j}$

Can we have  "${\rm div}(K(x)\nabla u)\in L^{2}(\Omega)\Rightarrow u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$"?

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: You have to assume $g\in H^{1/2}$.

Comment: thanks!  what should we do if we assume $g\in H^{1/2}$? can we get the last conclusion？